# How to get collection element in JPA named query

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Below is My Named query here in my output list of Test Case is repeating 
due to attribute.I need all attribute in one obj which are belongs to same test case

> "select t.Id,atr from TestCase t join t.attributes as atr"

```
public class TestCase {

@javax.persistence.Id
private Integer Id;

@Column(name="ui_order")
@OrderBy("uiorder desc")
private Integer uiorder;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="testCase")
@OrderBy("name DESC")
private Set<Attributes> attributes=new HashSet<Attributes>();
}


public class Attributes {

@Id
private Integer Id;

private String name;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="test_case_id")
private TestCase testCase;

}
```

output of query is

```
[["id":1,"attributes":{"name":"Battery","id":1}],["id":1,"attributes":{"name":"Fan","id":2}]
```

Desired Output is

```
[{"id":1,"attributes":[{"name":"Battery","id":1},{"name":"Fan","id":2}]}]
```

Comment: why is there an `@OrderBy` on an Integer field?!!! `@OrderBy` is for use on an ordered collection ...

Comment: You can't, as the results will mirror what the database would give you, which is one result per row in the table.  If you want collections, you are better off querying for the TestCase (fetch join attributes) and displaying the referenced collection yourself with your own toString method.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t FROM TestCase t LEFT JOIN FETCH t.attributes
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to group by id, so you just need to add GROUP BY

```
SELECT t.id, atr
FROM TestCase t JOIN t.attributes as atr
GROUP BY t.id
```

Comment: [{"id":1,"attributes":[{"name":"Battery","id":1}}] its giving only first attribute after grouping not all.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: [{"id":1,"attributes":[{"name":"Battery","id":1},{"name":"Fan","id":2}]}]